# VirtualBox says VM is out of space

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Virtualbox through vagrant. I'm running a provisioner which installs a bunch of packages through yum. The provisioner keeps halting, and when I look at VirtualBox, I see that the VM is paused. In the logs, there's an entry:

```
00:12:08.042247 Changing the VM state from 'SUSPENDING' to 'SUSPENDED'.
00:12:08.042839 Console: VM runtime error: fatal=false, errorID=BLKCACHE_IOERR message="The I/O cache encountered an error while updating data in medium "ahci-0-0" (rc=VERR_DISK_FULL). Make sure there is enough free space on the disk and that the disk is working properly. Operation can be resumed afterwards"
```

However, there is plenty of disk space available on the VM, according to `df`. I set up a `watch -n 0.5 df -h` (run `df -h` every half second), and there was never a shortage of space:

```
Every 0.5s: df -h                                                                    
Tue Nov 10 23:52:30 2015

Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  8.4G  2.3G  6.2G  27% /
devtmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.9G  8.4M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                497M  107M  391M  22% /boot
none                     233G  152G   82G  65% /vagrant
```

Furthermore, if I unpause the VM in VirtualBox, things just keep going as normal -- that is, until/unless it pauses again. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: try to enable the cache I/O host option, please review this question maybe it could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564644/virtualbox-returning-errorid-blkcache-ioerr/37481834#37481834